# how to integrate bhashsms gateway in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, sms

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed','payment_complete');
  function payment_complete($order_id)
{

$order=new Wc_order($order_id);
$order_meta = get_post_meta($order_id);
$shipping_first_name = $order_meta['_shipping_first_name'][0];
$phone=$order_meta['_billing_phone'][0];
$first_name=$order->billing_first_name;
$last_name=$order->billing_last_name;
$name=$first_name."".$last_name;
$mobile=$order->billing_mobile;
$items = $order->get_items();
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
$product_name = $item['name'];
$product_id = $item['product_id'];
$product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
$time=$item['timings'];
$slot=$item['time_slot'];
$qty= $item['qty'];
$date=$item['tour_date'];
}
$text="your message here";
$data="user=username&pass=password&sender=sendername&phone=".$phone."&priority=ndnd&stype=normal&text=".$text;
$ch = curl_init('http://bhashsms.com/api/sendmsg.php?');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
 echo $result; 
curl_close($ch);
}
```

Someone says this piece of code is working but i am newbie to wordpress , i want to know in which file to put that code or anyone knows bhashsms wordpress plugin